# Performance Improvement for nightly batch load

Tags: performance, amazon-eks

We run nightly batch with maximum load between 1-2 am but only able to process 2500-3000 Batches only. We receive around 10000 Batch load during that time and sometimes more. We want to increase the throughput so it processes close to 10000.

We are using AWS EKS cluster and tried increasing replicas from 5 to 6. We were expecting the throughput to increase by 500-600 Batches but that didn't happen.
We also tried to increase job processor at application level which could support more parallel processing, but no luck again.
We increased cache time to live at application level to 24 hours so that similar jobs which run daily could be already cached but that also didn't help.

Our observation has been that in the first hour there is slower process and after 2am onwards when less batches comes in then throughput increases to 3500 - 4500.

Please advise about the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you seeing the bottleneck? Is it the API can't create and schedule the pods fast enough. You increased pod replicas from 5 to 6 for the job itself or something processing the jobs? Are pods or nodes consuming all of their CPU/memory?